# How to initialize evaluation's local variables with tf.train.Scaffold?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the high level [`tf.contrib.learn.Experiment`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) object to interleave training and evaluation. However, I'm facing an issue with the local variables from the evaluation and metrics modules that are reported as non initialized:

```
Variables not initialized: mean/total, mean/count, eval_step
```

I provide a custom `local_init_op` to [`tf.train.Scaffold`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Scaffold) which basically looks like this:

```
scaffold = tf.train.Scaffold(
  local_init_op=tf.group(
    iterator.initializer,
    tf.tables_initializer(),
    tf.local_variables_initializer()))
```

(where `iterator` is a [`tf.contrib.data.Iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Iterator).)

which is then stored in a [`tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) to be returned by the [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator)'s `model_fn` function.

As I don't think `tf.local_variables_initializer()` operates lazily, it means these variables are not yet created.

So how to initialize them?

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found is to not use a custom `local_init_op` but rely on the default one which is built in `Scaffold.finalize`, when all variables are created.

To initialize my `iterator` I simply added it in the `TABLE_INITIALIZERS` collection:

```
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)
```